# Pagination for event query

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, the-events-calendar

I'm working on a WP_Query using the [Modern Tribe Events Calendar](http://tri.be/shop/wordpress-events-calendar/)

My problem is with pagination.

Is this the incorrect way to paginate the WP_Query or could there be another method for paginating the Events Calendar?

I found a [tutorial](http://tri.be/queries-and-pagination/) that uses the WPNavi plugin but I would like use core wordpress functions.

```
<?php 
$upcoming = new WP_Query();
$upcoming->query( array(
    'post_type'=> 'tribe_events',
    'eventDisplay' => 'upcoming',
    'posts_per_page' => 1)
);

if ($upcoming->have_posts()) : while ($upcoming->have_posts()) : $upcoming->the_post(); ?>

        <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'list/single', 'event' ) ?>

<?php endwhile;

else : 
    echo 'no upcoming events'; 
endif;

wp_reset_query(); 
?>

<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
```

Comment: Please do not add the answer to the question, use the _answer_ field instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using this solution.

My only concern is if its an appropriate solution.

```
 <?php 
    global $paged;
    $curpage = $paged ? $paged : 1;
    $upcoming = new WP_Query();
    $upcoming->query( array(
        'post_type'=> 'tribe_events',
        'eventDisplay' => 'upcoming',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $paged)
    );

    if ($upcoming->have_posts()) : while ($upcoming->have_posts()) : $upcoming->the_post(); ?>

        <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'list/single', 'event' ) ?>

    <?php endwhile;


    echo '<div id="navigation">';
        if ($curpage != 1) {
           echo '<a class="previous" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage-1 > 0 ? $curpage-1 : 1)).'">&lsaquo;</a>';
        }
        if ($curpage != $upcoming->max_num_pages) {
           echo '<a class="next" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage+1 <= $upcoming->max_num_pages ? $curpage+1 : $upcoming->max_num_pages)).'">&rsaquo;</a>';
        }            
    echo '</div>';

    endif;

    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`posts_nav_link()` works off the main query. Instead of invoking your own `$upcoming`, just use `query_posts( ... )` to temporarily overwrite it, and the corresponding template tags...

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'tribe_events',
        'eventDisplay'   => 'upcoming',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    )
);

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php tribe_get_template_part( 'list/single', 'event' ) ?>

<?php endwhile;

else : 
    echo 'no upcoming events'; 
endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
When I try to include posts_nav_link(); I get the page links and it pages correctly according to the number of posts but it only shows the first post on each page.

Comment: That's because you have `posts_per_page => 1`...